# The best overloaded method match for 'ColConfigSubsystem.Database.GetChromeMakeByYear(int)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I have an event in C# that populates dropdown lists from a class file (database.cs) with the associated values from a different database via oracle stored procedures contained in the class file mentioned above.  This is the code that I am currently using:

```
    ///<summary>
    ///Populates the model dropdownlist with available chrome data associated with 
    ///the year selected
    /// </summary>
    private void PopulateChromeModel()
    {
        //define a counter
        int itemCounter = 1;

        //create a database object
        Database cmake = new Database();

        //call GetChromeMakeByYear to retrieve the available models according to 
        //the year
        DataTable table = cmake.GetChromeMakeByYear(ddlVehicleYear.SelectedItem);

        Trace.Write("populating models");

        //create a flag showing whether an item should be selected.  Preset it to false
        bool selected = false;

        //we may need to select, then later deselect, an item based on the model.
        int selectedItemByModel = 0;

        //preset the current selected code to ""
        string currentSelectedCode = "";

        //define a flag to indicate whether we've already selected an item.  Preset it to false.
        bool hasSelected = false;

        //create a list item for the 0 position
        ListItem firstItem = new ListItem("-- SELECT --", "");

        //first see if there is a currently selected item.  If so, set the current selected model.
        //this is done because we have to clear all of the selected items before adding the new list.
        //but we want to be able to select the model that is already selected.
        if (ddlVehicleModel.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            currentSelectedCode = ddlVehicleModel.SelectedValue;
        }

        //clear any items from the list
        ddlVehicleModel.Items.Clear();

        //add the first item
        ddlVehicleModel.Items.Add(firstItem);

        //loop through the table and add items for each row.
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            //get this record's chrome id
            string id = row["CHROME_ID"].ToString();

            //get this record's make
            string make = row["CHROME_MAKE"].ToString();

            //set a flag specifying whether the item should be selected based on year
            bool selectBasedOnYear = false;

            if (currentSelectedCode == id)
            {
                selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                selected = false;
                selectBasedOnYear = false;
            }

            Trace.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}: {3}", id, make, selected, selectBasedOnYear));

            //create a new list item for this model
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem(id, make);

            //if we have thrown either selected flag and we have not already selected an item, 
            //mark this option as selected
            if ((selected || selectBasedOnYear) && !hasSelected)
            {
                Trace.Write("-- Either selected or selectedBasedOnYear was true, and hasSelected was false");

                //first make sure the first item is deselected
                firstItem.Selected = false;
                Trace.Write("-- deselected the first item.");

                //next deselect and items that were selected due to year.  This allows the user selected
                //region to override the default model for year.
                if (selectBasedOnYear != null)
                {
                    Trace.Write(string.Format(" -- deselecting item {0}, which was selected due to year", selectBasedOnYear));
                    ddlVehicleMake.Items[selectedItemByModel].Selected = false;
                }

                //select this item
                newItem.Selected = true;
                Trace.Write(" -- selected the current item");

                //only throw the hasSelected flag if this was a user-selected region
                if (selected)
                {
                    hasSelected = true;
                    Trace.Write(" -- set hasSelected to true");
                }

            }

            //add the model to the list
            ddlVehicleMake.Items.Add(newItem);

            itemCounter++;
        }

        //if there's no items selected and we have more than just the default item, 
        //default to the first item
        if (ddlVehicleMake.Items.Count > 0 && !hasSelected && selectedItemByModel == 0)
        {
            ddlVehicleMake.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

The error is being thrown at the following line:

```
        //call GetChromeMakeByYear to retrieve the available models according to 
        //the year
        DataTable table = cmake.GetChromeMakeByYear(ddlVehicleYear.SelectedItem);
```

I have included my inline comments and summary to help with the scope of this event.  I am not quite sure what the reason is for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbox the value to an integer.

```
DataTable table = cmake.GetChromeMakeByYear((int)ddlVehicleYear.SelectedItem);
```

When items are retrieved from a dropdown list they are retrieved in the form of objects, because you can store any type of data in them. The compiler doesn't know that the item you are specifying in the list is in fact an integer (and not say a string) and so doesn't know what function you are trying to call.

More about unboxing and boxing here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: ok I did as you said and it threw another error "Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'int'.  Do I have to cast it to an int?

Comment: @MaximusPrime: try  `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`

Comment: Hmmm...I tried using SelectedValue and it threw another error 'Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: In that case you need to convert it instead of unboxing or casting it. `int.Parse(SelectedValue)` should work. This is of course if the string is a valid integer. As a side note it's normally better to use `int date; int.TryParse(SelectedValue, out date)` just in case.

Comment: It does work however now it throws a cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Data.DataTable' error?  Now I am thoroughly confused

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DataTable table = cmake.GetChromeMakeByYear((int) ddlVehicleYear.SelectedValue);
```